# Do attribute names in an Android library need to be prefixed?

Tags: android, xml

I've read (and confirmed with testing) that resource value names (Strings, Drawables, dimensions, etc.) should have a prefix at the beginning (generally the library's name) to avoid name conflicts, because a project that uses the library and declares a resource with a matching name will overwrite the library's resource.

What I'm unclear on is whether the names of `attr` attributes inside a `<declare-styleable>` should also be prefixed. Since they are wrapped within the `<declare-styleable>`, are they protected from over-writing? Within Java code, their resource names are automatically prefixed with the name of the `<declare-styleable>`, but when used within XML files, they are not.

I'm guessing that their usage is context sensitive. That in my custom Preference's code, when I call `context.obtainStyledAttributes()` with a specific styleable, it is only at that point that the XML attributes are interpretted as specific types. If I declare a Preference styleable attribute named `"min"` of type `float` and use it in my project, it will not matter that there is an attribute named `"min"` in the v7.preference library's SeekBarPreference styleable of type `int`, because SeekBar doesn't use my styleable when calling `obtainStyledAttributes()`.

So if my assumption is correct, there's no reason the compiler would be consolidating attributes by name like that. But custom attribute styling is a complex beast in Android, and I'm not sure if I'm missing something in my testing. It would be nice to omit the prefixes in my library's attribute names for ease of use/documentation.

If the `<declare-styleable>` is defining attributes for a Style, then I think it's still safe from conflicts, because Styles don't merge. They only reference each other from their own attributes. If I understand them correctly--they are somewhat convoluted to me.

On a related note, is there any reason view IDs should be prefixed? I'm thinking yes, because my library view exists within a project's view structure and a user of the library calls `findViewById()` on an ID that matches one of mine, I could envision scenarios where the search turns up my view first and trips them up. But Google's own appcompat libraries take no such precaution, so I'm unsure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After studying documentation and AOSP source code, I've come to the conclusion that *yes*, you *should* prefix attribute names.

Resource attributes are not `<declare-styleable>` local. They are all global. When you declare a resource attribute (which can be done inside or outside of a `<declare-styleable>`), you name it and give it a format type:

```
<attr name="my_attribute" format="string" /> <!-- This is a declaration -->
```

When you reference a resource attribute (which is only done from within a `<declare-styleable>`), you list its name but not its format.

```
<attr name="my_attribute" /> <!-- This is a reference -->
```

Lint shows an error if you try to declare two attributes with the same name.

The fact that you can declare an attribute from within a `<declare-styleable>` is merely a convenience for code conciseness. It does not imply a limited scope. If you are planning to use the same attribute in multiple styleables, it's probably good practice to put its declaration outside of any `<declare-styleable>`, so it can be found easily.

One oddity I've noticed is that Lint doesn't show an error if two different libraries have overlapping attribute declarations. I suppose it doesn't cause an issue if they both have the same format type. I haven't checked to see what happens if they don't.

As for why Google doesn't prefix attribute names in AppCompat, I figure they want it to be very easy to use, and almost interchangeable with AOSP xml code, so they want the attribute names to match similar attribute names in AOSP. And so they deemed the simplicity of use outweighs the risk. What I suspect they overlook is how disjointed and lacking their documentation is on setting up and using styleables and attributes, so it's not obvious what to watch out for when setting up our own custom views and preferences.